# how to give $('inputs') each function as to store data as key value pair in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

```
  $("#btnSubmit").click($('#form1 input'), function() {
      var data = new Object();
      for (var i =1; i < form1.length-1; i++) {
              data[i] = form1[i].name + ":" + form1[i].value ;
      }
      document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
```

How to avoid view state and how to get string json output?

Comment: i have made a simple fiddle , see if it can do https://jsfiddle.net/3shg35uf/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btnSubmit").click($('#form1 input'), function() {
      var data = [];
      for (var prop in form1) {
            data.push(form1[prop]);
      }
      document.write(data);
  });
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43uVr/)**

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to select only desired input elements is, to put a class on them then select elements based on that class. `$('#form1 input.post').each(...)`

Another way is to select all input elements and keep a not selector for those which you want to exclude.

To parse array back from json string you can use `$.parseJSON(jsonString)`

You can see the sample fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7tacd24v/).